# Which iOS remote connection apps permit persistent connections that do not drop in the background?

Tags: remote-desktop

Some well known remote connection apps for iOS include RealVNC, TeamViewer, AnyDesk, Duet Display Air, Microsoft RD, and Chrome Remote Desktop.

Of the above, the only one that I know keeps the remote connection active even when the app is in the background is Microsoft RD, but this app cannot connect to a Mac, and it forces landscape mode and does not permit portrait mode.

Which remote desktop apps for iOS do not drop in the background? Especially ones that can connect to a server that can be installed on a Mac?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

NoMachine works if backgrounded.
I don't know how long for, I just tested a couple of minutes. If the app gets 'parked' due to being too far back in the list of recents then no doubt it will lose the connection.

iOS app -  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nomachine/id874286563 [US store, change as appropriate]
Mac app - https://www.nomachine.com [also available for Win, nix & android]

I've only switched to this recently, after years of other apps, which eventually seem to want money from me for my twice-a-year usage, or are too hard to poke through my non-UPnP gateway.